# Google Calendar multiple entry for same calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar API for automation, where I search a calendar with particular Keywords and make the entry of the same in a google sheet.
I fetch the Calendar ID, attendees' names and emails, and the name of the calendar in the sheet columns.
However, I have observed multiple times that instead of creating one entry per calendar, two entries of the same calendar with different calendar IDs are being added in the sheet. Below is one of those entries.

http://prntscr.com/1wtbse4

The time & content of the entries are the same as they are of the same calendar, but the calendar ID is different.

Please share any ideas whether this is a bug or how we can fix this?